# CSS messing with my code

Tags: html, css, text, prompt

My page fails to display properly whenever it can access to the CSS file I was provided. When it's just the .html, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl7tB.png), when it has access to the css and the image files it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/js2QA.jpg) and when it has only the css it just has the small orange rectangle you can see in the second picture. It's supposed to show the text input boxes over the background.

I'd love to know what's wrong with it and how I can fix it, here's what the code looks like

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans|Droid+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Find The Twin</title>

    <link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>
    <!-- LOGIN -->
    <div class="login"  id="loguin">
        <div class="cabezalTarjeta">login | registro</div>
        <h2>Mail:</h2>
        <div class="respuestas clearfix">
            <input type="text" id="mail"/>
        </div>
        <h2>Nombre:</h2>
        <div class="respuestas clearfix">
            <input type="text" id="nombre"/>
        </div>
        <h2>País:</h2>
        <div class="respuestas clearfix">
            <select id="pais">
                <option>Seleccione su país...</option>
                <option>Argentina</option>
                <option>Brasil</option>
                <option>Paraguay</option>
                <option>Perú</option>
                <option>Uruguay</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <h2>Edad:</h2>
        <div class="respuestas clearfix">
            <input type="text" id="edad"/>
        </div>
        <input type="button" id="comenzarJuego" value="Comenzar juego">
    </div><!-- FIN LOGIN -->

    <!-- INICIO CONFIGURACION -->
    <div class="configuracion" id="configuracion">
        <div class="cabezalTarjeta">Configuración</div>

        <h2>Medidas</h2>
             <div class="respuestas clearfix">
            <h2>Ancho:</h2>
            <input type="text" id="ancho"/>
            <h2>Alto:</h2>              
            <input type="text" id="alto"/>
        </div>
        <input type="button" id="asignarValores" value="Asignar valores">
    </div><!-- FIN CONFIGURACION -->

    <div class="contenido">
        <!-- INICIO CABEZAL -->
        <div class="cabezal clearfix">
            <img src="img/logo.png">
            <div id="intentos"></div>
            <!-- DIV PARA PONER EL MENU ADENTRO -->
             <div class="contenedorMenu clearfix">


             </div><!-- FIN DIV PARA EL MENU -->

        </div>
        <!-- FIN CABEZAL -->

        <!-- INICIO JUEGO -->
        <div class="contenedorInterior">
            <div class="juego">
                <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="img/piezas/img_vacio.png"></td><td><img src="img/piezas/img_vacio.png"></td><td><img src="img/piezas/img_vacio.png"></td><td><img src="img/piezas/img_vacio.png"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><img src="img/piezas/img_vacio.png"></td><td><img src="img/piezas/img_cebra.png"></td><td><img src="img/piezas/img_vacio.png"></td><td><img src="img/piezas/img_vacio.png"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><img src="img/piezas/img_vacio.png"></td><td><img src="img/piezas/img_vacio.png"></td><td><img src="img/piezas/img_hipopotamo.png"></td><td><img src="img/piezas/img_vacio.png"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><img src="img/piezas/img_vacio.png"></td><td><img src="img/piezas/img_vacio.png"></td><td><img src="img/piezas/img_vacio.png"></td><td><img src="img/piezas/img_vacio.png"></td>
                </tr>

                </table>

            </div> <!-- FIN JUEGO -->


         <!-- EJEMPLO DE TABLAS CON DATOS 
         <div class="tablas">
            <table>
            <tr><th>País</th><th>Promedio</th></tr>
            <tr><td>Uruguay</td><td>11.5</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Brasil</td><td>16</td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        -->
        </div><!-- FIN CONTENEDOR INTERIOR -->


    </div> <!-- FIN CONTENEDOR-->



    <img src="img/cometa.png" class="cometa">
    <img src="img/plane.png" class="avion">
</body>
```

And here's the css file

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}

body
{
    background:url(../img/background.jpg) fixed;
    background-size:cover;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
}

.overlay
{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index: 110;
    position:absolute;
    display: none;
}


.login, .configuracion
{
    width:280px;
    /*height:420px;*/
    background-color: #FC0;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#000;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:50%;
    z-index:120;
    margin-left:-140px;
    display:none;
}

.cabezalTarjeta
{
    background-color: #E67739;
    width:240px;
    height:30px;
    margin:15px;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:70px 10px 0px 0px;
    text-align:right;
    font-weight:bold;
}
 #intentos{
     float:right;
      color:#333;
      background-color: #E67739;
    padding:10px ;
    margin:0px;
    font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
    font-size:25px;
    line-height: 28px;} 
.tarjeta h2, .login h2, .configuracion h2
{
    color:#333;
    padding:10px 15px 0 15px;
    margin:0px;
    font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
    font-size:25px;
    line-height: 28px;
}

.tarjeta input[type="radio"]
{
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    display:block;
    margin:5px 2px 0px 10px;
}

.login input[type="text"], select,  .configuracion input[type="text"]
{
    width: 240px;
    height:30px;
    margin:5px 2px 0px 14px;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
}

.tarjeta label, .configuracion label
{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    clear:right;
    margin: 5px 10px 0px 3px;
    width:230px;
}


#botonRespuesta, #comenzarJuego, #reiniciarJuego, #asignarValores
{
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
    margin:0px auto 15px auto;
    color:#29505E;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:15px;

}

.contenido
{
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.juego table
{
    margin:0 auto;
}

.contenido ul
{
    float:right;
    margin-top:50px;


}

.contenido li
{
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#FFF;
    padding:15px;
    background-color:#FC0;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.cometa
{
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    top:100px;
}

.avion
{
    position:fixed;
    left:10px;
    top:150px;
}

.tablas
{
    margin:50px 0;
}

.tablas table
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size:14px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    color:#EEE;
    width:500px;
}

.tablas td, .tablas th
{
    padding:10px 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
    text-align:center;
}

.tablas th
{
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: If the spanish words cause confusion I can resubmit doing my best to translate it

Comment: your both pictures do not seem to correlate.

Comment: I too am confused. Can you elaborate a bit on what you are expecting or trying to do, because it's not readily apparent to me.

Comment: You should ask whoever did your css to fix it

Comment: That's what I'm confused about, without the CSS loading the html shows what's in the first picture, with it it shows what's in the second.

Comment: The first screen is login and configuration for the game, those are supposed to show up in the second one.

Comment: [**Here is a jsBin**](http://jsbin.com/ejOWUpoK/1/edit) showing the problem

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way but it is invaluable to understand html and css and how they work together. If you plan to play around with web apps more then I'd make an attempt to learn what's what :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the css for the input elements to Z-index higher than the elements of the html code you want behind it.  By default, everything lies on z-index:0;

If you want something to "layer" above that, simply put z-index:1; or z-index:100;  This is already being used in your code for the overlay (E.g. z-index:110;)  That's probably fine, but if you want your fields above that, then simply put z-index:111 or higher for the input fields in your css page.